# Evaluate $\int \frac{x}{x^4+5}dx$

Tags: integration

> $$\int \frac{x}{x^4+5}dx$$

$u=x^2$

$du=2xdx\Rightarrow \frac{du}{2}=xdx$

$$\int \frac{x}{x^4+5}=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{du}{u^2+5}$$

I want to get to the expression in the form of $\frac{da}{a^2+1}$ so I factor out $5$ to get to:

$$\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{du}{5[(\frac{u}{\sqrt{5}})^2+1]}$$

$\frac{du}{5[(\frac{u}{\sqrt{5}})^2+1]}$ is in the form of $\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{\frac{5c}{d}}$ so if I factor out the $5$ should it be $$\int \frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{5}\frac{du}{[(\frac{u}{\sqrt{5}})^2+1]}$$
or 
$$\int \frac{1}{2}*5\frac{du}{[(\frac{u}{\sqrt{5}})^2+1]}$$

Comment: The first is correct. You get $\tan^{-1}(x^2/\sqrt{5})\over 2\sqrt 5$

Comment: @GeorgSaliba but I first must do another substitution $t=\frac{u}{\sqrt{5}}$?

Comment: $1/(5A)=(1/5)\times (1/A)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last line isn't correct, you can procced as follows:

$$\int \frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{5}\frac{du}{[(\frac{u}{\sqrt{5}})^2+1]}=\frac 1 {10}\int\frac{du}{u^2/5+1}$$

Set $t=\frac{u}{\sqrt5}$ and $dt=\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}du$

$$=\frac{1}{2\sqrt 5}\int\frac{dt}{t^2+1}$$

$$=\frac{\arctan t}{2\sqrt 5}=\frac{\arctan \left(u/\sqrt 5\right)}{2\sqrt 5}=\frac{\arctan \left(x^2/\sqrt 5\right)}{2\sqrt 5}+C$$

Answer (score 1):

The First is correct. Let $t=u/\sqrt5$ then $dt=du/\sqrt5$:
$$\frac 12 \frac 1{\sqrt5}\int\frac {dt}{1+t^2}=\frac 12 \frac 1{\sqrt5}\tan^{-1}(t)+c=\frac 12 \frac 1{\sqrt5}\tan^{-1}(\frac {x^2}{\sqrt5})+c$$